# WPF: is there a way to do inline formatting?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to use inline formatting (like Swing's HTML tagging within labels) with WPF? I could not find any documentation.

Comment: Can you use a RichTextBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextBlock (there may be others) can make use of several inline formatting elements.

[example lifted verbatim from: http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/03/14/245-easily-inline-text-formatting-codes-with-textblock-control ]

```
<TextBlock Margin="10" Height="100" FontSize="14" Width="290" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    We <Bold>few</Bold>, we happy <Bold>few</Bold>, we band of <Underline>brothers</Underline>;
For he to-day that sheds his <Italic>blood</Italic> with me
Shall be my <Underline>brother</Underline>; be he ne'er so <Italic>vile</Italic>,
This day shall <Bold>gentle</Bold> his <Italic>condition</Italic>;"
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, but XAML uses [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#attribute_syntax_properties). Just like in HTML you can say `<element attribute="foo"></element>`